# What are these black components?

Tags: power-electronics

[image]

One of these black things is burnt and according to the technician it have to be replaced , and when I asked him: what is this he said : IC ????!!! 
Well, What are these?
Sorry for bad English

———————————————————————————
Hello everybody.
Thank you very much for your responses.
I meant the surface mount resistor (as it seems to be), well here more clear photo, and it is clear the burnt component is on the right (down circle) and on the above circle there is broken component (It seems the case) , is it transistor? 
Thanks
[image]

Comment: I see several resistors, most probably two capacitors and one transistor or IC in black capsules. Which one are you refering to?

Comment: Please mark the component that you are asking about.

Comment: For reference, the small black rectangles with the 3 digit numbers on them are resistors with resistances of "digit 1, digit 2" times 10 ^ digit3. For example, "124" is 12 * 10^4 ohms.

Comment: IC stands for integrated circuit. It is a chip that has a circuit integrated into it as opposed to being multiple discrete components. There is a 3 pin IC in that photo that looks like a transistor. Is that the burnt component? It is hard to tell from the photo. Unless you can read the marking on it, or have a schematic it would be hard to find the replacement part.

Comment: The 3 pin thing can also be a voltage regulator or a voltage reference (i.e. IC). You have to trace the full circuit to figure out what makes most sense in that location (BJT or mosfet transistor, or IC). Once you have the circuit, you can also figure out a suitable replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are **surface mount resistors**. The numbers indicate the resistance. Below is how these numbers are formatted to tell you can interpret that resistance.

Picture from a blog, called "[Richardo's Workbench](http://blog.ricardoarturocabral.com/2010/10/smd-resistors-cheat-sheet.html)"

[image]

Side note: I do see a surface mount transistor below that diode on the top left. Perhaps your technician was referring to that?

**Since you edited question to clarify:** My answer still stands. However, that top circle shows a transistor and the bottom circuit shows those resistors I mentioned earlier in this answer. The black component with only two leads are *ferrite beads* as mentioned in the comments of my answer.

Comment: @MohammedZainudin I feel like I should clarify on this answer that not all the components in the photo are resistors. It looks like there is also capacitors, a transistor, some diodes, and some ferrite beads. The transistor is the only part that could really be called an IC

Comment: @I.Wolfe You're right about that. Once the OP clarifies, then I'll edit my answer. However, capacitors are more of a beige color and diodes are more of an auburn color.

Answer (score 3):

**If** it is an IC **and** it's **visible** in the photo, it has to be the 3-lead device. The other parts are diodes and capacitors (neither is black) and resistors (and maybe a couple ferrite beads).